# How can I use async/await instead of a promise (.then)

Tags: es6-promise

I'm trying to use async/await in my project instead of .then, but it's throwing me an error

here is my code:

```
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => async dispatch => {
    axios
        .post('/api/users/register', userData)
        await (res => history.push('/login'))
        .catch(err => dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
        );
};
```

and this is the error i get back

**Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): (intermediate value).catch is not a function**

Comment: If you show us some code and the error it will be much more helpful

Comment: " it's trowing be an error" —And that error says what?

Answer (score 2):

`await` isn't a function that you replace `then()` with. It is a keyword that you put before an expression that resolves as a promise. When you use it, you also replace the `catch()` method with a regular try/catch.

```
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        await axios.post('/api/users/register', userData);
        history.push('/login');
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data
        })
    );
};
```